# thunder client not show in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, thunderclient

I have installed the thunder client extension. Thunder client should show like this in side bar.
[image: Thunder Client]

But in My VS Code this is missing, How can I solve it?
[image: Thunder Client error]

Comment: Hi, try installing previous version of the extension. some users have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, what happened to me was that Thunder Client was set to the "Secondary Side Bar", which you can access going to:

View > Appearance > Secondary Side Bar

If you want it to be placed back to the primary side bar, then you can simply drag and drop it from the secondary side bar to the primary and you will be good to go.

[image: Screenshot of the setting]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
**Ctrl+Shift+R?**
```

Alternatively, you can try downgrading the Thunder Client version and see if that solves the problem as there have been multiple reports of the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Thunder Client
2. Reinstall Thunder Client
3. Press Ctrl+Shift+R

Answer (score 0):

uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in restricted mode in your current workspace, Thunder extension will not be available to you.
[image]

If you click on the "Restricted" button in the bottom left and then "Trust", the Thunder tab will return.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just like the top answer, mine also got moved into the secondary bar somehow.
just go to view > appearance > secondary side bar.
Thunder client will pop up on the side. just click and drag its icon back into the primary side bar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it did not load because I did not have vscode in Applications

[vscode in Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwegT.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35794262)